# Reports using different interfaces

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, security, custom-reports, salesforce-classic

I have created a report using classic but when another user creates the same report in lightning, some records are not displayed.

Comment: Can you add the steps to reproduce this behavior? Do you see any pattern of records not being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 reasons why something doesn't show up in a Report or Dashboard:

1. It does not meet the scope or filter criteria of the Report
2. The User does not have at least Read access to it
3. It does not exist

Bases on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324873&type=1&mode=1)
try these suggestions:-

> (1) Is the appropriate Report Type selected? If you have multiple
> relationships built between two objects you will need to select the
> appropriate one to get the correct results. Example: If you are using
> an "Opportunities with Contact Roles" report type, any Opportunity
> without a Contact Role will not appear.
>
> (2) Verify that the records expected fall into the TIME FRAME
> identified on the report. If you do not see any records that fall
> within the defined reporting time frame, then no records will be
> displayed on the report.
>
> (3) Verify that the records expected fall into the FILTER CRITERIA
> section on the report. Example: If the record is an Opportunity that
> is "Closed/Won" and the Opportunity Status in the filter is "Open,"
> that record will not be displayed. You will also want to review the
> built-in filters such as "All opportunities" or "My team's
> opportunities".
>
> (4) Have fields from a Child Object been selected to be displayed,
> filtered upon, or summed? Adding a field from a Child Object may
> result in the report dropping rows for which no related record exists.
>
> (5) Does every user have a role? (displayed on user records) Activity
> and Opportunity reports rely on the Role or Territory Hierarchy to
> determine what records should be accessible to a user. Users without a
> Role assigned will not have their records displayed within these
> reports. This also applies for System Administrators, though as an
> Administrator you will be permitted to click through the "Organization
> Drill Down."
>
> (6) Reports created using a Custom Report Type do not follow the
> sharing rules on the Opportunity and Activity objects. Example: When
> running an "Opportunities with Products" report, if there are no
> Product or Pricebook fields selected to be displayed, the report type
> will be treated as an "Opportunities" report. Once a field is used
> from either of these child objects, it will require that relationship
> be defined. When using the standard report type "Activities with
> Cases," Activities will not show up unless it has a populated Contact
> Name field, even if it is related to a case. This usually occurs when
> an Activity is created through Email.  When using the custom report
> type "Case with Activities," Activities related to a Case will show up
> on the report, even without relation to a Contact. (7) Reports based
> on a "with" Custom Report Type may show varying results depending on
> fields that are selected to be displayed.   Please view the following
> article for more details: Report 'Record Count' changes when 'Details'
> are hidden or exposed.
>
> (8) Check your personal Time Zone setting.  Users based in different
> Time Zones may see different results within reports. When comparing
> the results you see in a report against the results a co-worker sees,
> be sure you are both assigned the appropriate Time Zone within your
> User Detail.
>
> (9) Verify access to filtering fields.   If your profile does not have
> "Read" access to the fields used as report filters, these filters will
> not be applied when you are viewing a report. This may lead to
> different results returned for different users. Contact your System
> Administrator if you think you should have access to a specific field
> that is not currently visible.
>
> (10) An "Accounts" Standard Report Type uses a "My territories'
> accounts" or "My territory team's accounts" filter.  If an Account
> belongs to multiple Territories to which the running user also
> belongs, then the Account will appear multiple times in the report.
> Using "My territory team's accounts" will result in similar behavior
> when an Account belongs to multiple Territories for which the running
> user belongs or any descendant territories. If you would like Accounts
> to return a single row in such a report, consider using a Custom
> Report Type.